# Reset bootstrap tab structure after Ajax Get

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bunch of big pages(around 12 of them which I omitted) that I am loading with ajax.
I am loading the pages in to Tabs.

```
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="Summary_Tab" class="tab-pane active"></div>
                <div id="Health_A" class="tabe-pane fade "></div>
                <div id="Risk_A" class="tabe-pane fade"></div>
            </div>
```

This is how I load

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$.get('Health_A', function (data) {
    $("#Health_A").html(data);
});
$.get('Risk_A', function (data) {
    $("#Risk_A").html(data);
});
});
```

Now what happens is that I get blank blocks that represent what I got from ajax in a row that make the page really long. The new tab isnt really invisible, its not seen but is clickable. If I click on a tab toggle the tab is shown but in the middle of the page not at the start of it.
What I need to do as far as I can think is reset the bootstrap so it will make all the tabs invisible properly and all the lengths of them small.

Or any other ideas? What to do?

Comment: Is your Ajax result a HTML. if so that you can just Append the Ajax HTML content with previous one. Ofcourse You can style your HTML with HTML element and CSS

Comment: But thats exactly what I do. Hence the .html(data);

Comment: is the html in the divs if you check it in the source

Comment: Yes. The html is in the divs. I am trying to say that the divs are filled but they arent completly invisible. They are white and blank but clickable. It feels like a bootstrap bug